# Minimum but not positive definite neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, examples-counterexamples

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. It is clearly the case that $\bar x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a local minimizer if $\nabla f(\bar x)=0$ and there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$
H f(x) \text{ is positive semidefinite for all }x\in B_\varepsilon(\bar x).
$$

My question is: If $Hf(x)$ is *not* positive semidefinite in a *neighborhood* of $\bar x$ and still $\nabla f(\bar x)=0$, are there examples of $f$ where $\bar x$ is still a local minimizer? I thought about this, but if I draw such a function up in $\mathbb{R}$, it function looks non-smooth in $\bar x$. Also, because of continuity of eigenvalues, it can not be the case that $Hf(\bar x)$ is positive definite.

I have not found an example yet. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the squared distance to the unit circle,
$$f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2-1)^2.$$

Clearly every point on the unit circle is a local minimum of $f$. However, $Hf$ is indefinite when $x^2+y^2<1$ since for $v = (-y,x)$,
$$v^T [Hf(x,y)] v = 4(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-1).$$

Comment: Thank you! $Hf$ evaluated in what point?

Comment: @Meowdog At $(x,y)$.